# Construction of normals to parabola across external point

Tags: conic-sections, geometric-construction

I know this is a popular problem for algebra; I am looking for a constructive way to find the normal(s) to a parabola across an external point.

The obvious guess is that one needs to find the circle that contains all the foots. I have [found in the literature](https://archive.org/details/jstor-2971798/page/n1/mode/2up) a constructive recipe but it uses algebra, basically one takes coordinates centered on the vertex, horizontal abscisa being the axis of the parabola, and then to find the circle:

- The vertical cordinate is 1/4 of the coordinate of the external point A
- The horizontal coordinate is the focal distance OF plus half the coordinate of A.

[image: Barton's method]

Well, [it works](https://www.geogebra.org/m/dfv9xyzb), but it is sort of unsatisfactory, as it clearly uses the knowledge of the algebraic solution without any intuition from the properties of conics. I wonder which other approaches exist.

Comment: Did you find any reference to this "Harvey's theorem" which is mentioned in the source you cited?

Comment: @Intelligentipauca only some discusion about if it is a typo for "Hervey". Well, if it were a typo, I'd not discard it to be a theorem of Halley himself.